# Repeated regex capture for font-lock

Tags: regular-expressions, font-lock

Let's say I have a language which looks like this:

```
anchor (item something item some thing item some item thing) item item
```

and that I'm playing with font-lock a bit. I would like to highlight "anchor" as being a function and every "item" in the parens as well.

I tried the following:

```el
(setq test-font-lock-keywords
      `(
        ("\\<anchor\\>" (0 font-lock-function-name-face)
         ("\\<item\\>" nil nil (0 font-lock-constant-face))
         )
        )
)

(define-derived-mode test-mode fundamental-mode
  "test mode"
  "Test mode"
  (kill-all-local-variables)
  (interactive)
  (setq font-lock-defaults '(test-font-lock-keywords))
  )
```

My problem is that it considers every "item" word that comes after an "anchor" until the *end* of the line. The words "item item" in the end of my example should thus not receive syntax highlighting.
There may be a way to achieve this with a *post-form* but I'm not sure that's how it's meant to be used or how to do it anyway.

So I tried with the following, much less sexy regular expression:

```el
(setq regexp "\\(\\<anchor\\>\\)[\t ]*(\\(?:\\(item\\)\\|[^)]\\)*)")

(setq test-font-lock-keywords
      `(
        (,regexp (1 font-lock-function-name-face) (2 font-lock-constant-face))
       )
)
```

And it only highlights the last found "item" before the parens. How can I make this regex capture every "item" here represented with index 2?

Comment: If you use `define-derived-mode`, you should not need `kill-all-local-variables` and `interactive`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a little-known secret hidden in the *pre-match form*. This is from the built-in help of the `font-lock-keywords` variable:

> if PRE-MATCH-FORM returns a position greater than the position after
>   PRE-MATCH-FORM is evaluated, that position is used as the limit of the search.

Below, the pre-match form set the end of the parentesis following `anchor` as the end of the search:

```
'(("\\_<anchor *("
   (0 font-lock-function-name-face)
   ("\\_<\\item\\_>"
    ;; Pre-match form -- limit the sub-search to the end of the argument list.
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (match-end 0))
      (backward-char)
      (ignore-errors
        (forward-sexp))
      (point))
    ;; Post-match form
    (goto-char (match-end 0))
    (0 font-lock-constant-face))))
```

Note: If you set `font-lock-multiline` to a non-nil value, this works even when the `anchor` construct span multiple lines.

Comment: Is that a secret?  I think that is the purpose of the PRE-MATCH form.  `The forms pre-form and post-form can be used to initialize before, and cleanup after, anchored-matcher is used. Typically, pre-form is used to move point to some position relative to the match of matcher, before starting with anchored-matcher. post-form might be used to move back, before resuming with matcher.`  from: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Search_002dbased-Fontification.html . ps: I love font-lock-studio. Thanks for the effort and contribution. Feels like sorcery.

Comment: The pre- and post-match forms are often used for the things you quoted (moving the point around, cleanup, etc.). The "secret" I was referring to is that the *value* the pre-match form evaluates to, when an integer, is used by font-lock as the search limit for the inner anchored regexp. -- Thanks for your kind words regarding font-lock-studio. I've been writing font-lock rules for a long time and had the idea in my head for quite some time. Once, when I got stuck with one of my font-lock packages, I put it on hold, wrote font-lock-studio, and used that to finish the original package.