# How to highlight in different colors for variables inside `fstring` on python-mode

Tags: python, syntax-highlighting, coloring

I am using `python-mode` which colors the parameters.

When I concatinate strings the variable color is represented as different:
[image]

On the other hand, if I use `fstring`, the variable is not represented as different color:

[image: str]

Please note that, if I enter non-existing variable, `python-mode` detects it:

[image]

**[Q]** Is there any way to give a color to variables inside a `fstring` under `python-mode`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this will do it for Emacs versions < 27.1

```
(require 'python)

(setq python-font-lock-keywords
      (append python-font-lock-keywords
          '(;; this is the full string.
        ;; group 1 is the quote type and a closing quote is matched
        ;; group 2 is the string part
        ("f\\(['\"]\\{1,3\\}\\)\\(.+?\\)\\1"
         ;; these are the {keywords}
         ("{[^}]*?}"
          ;; Pre-match form
          (progn (goto-char (match-beginning 0)) (match-end 0))
          ;; Post-match form
          (goto-char (match-end 0))
          ;; face for this match
          (0 font-lock-variable-name-face t))))))
```

For later versions replace `python-font-lock-keywords` with `python-font-lock-keywords-maximum-decoration`.

I think this works on all strings now, including multiline ones (that seems to be a tricky one in general though). I left the {} in the highlight, they get replaced and that made sense to me.

Here is what it looks like for me:
[image]

font lock is hard!

The two other posts I looked at related to this are:

1. [Repeated regex capture for font-lock](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12110/repeated-regex-capture-for-font-lock)
2. [Python mode - custom syntax highlighting](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/33675/python-mode-custom-syntax-highlighting).

Comment: It works perfect (I pasted into `.emacs` file) but when I use it few other `python-mode` colorings are gone, is there any way to use it but keep the `python-mode` colorings as well? Such as comments color was red but become white again. Also strings inside `""` was green but become white.

Comment: Please see the color change for the strings inside `""` => https://gist.github.com/avatar-lavventura/5af25ccc3de7e07b537fce2f14c6aac2 @John Kitchin

Comment: I think with the new version you can get rid of the font-lock-keywords-only setting, then this works for everything but mulitline f-strings. see teh new picture above.

Comment: This may be challenging by what if I have `dict` inside a string, ex: `f"received: {jobInfo["received"]}"` //`received` string is seen as a invalid syntac on `python-mode`

Comment: That probably is invalid. You can't use the same kind of quotes for the dictionary key here. Try f'received {jobInfo["received"]}' instead.

Comment: Coloring get confused if multiple strings (`""`) or fstrings (`f""`) on the same line. Example: `["bash", f"{PATH}/check.sh", jobKey.replace("=", "", 1)]` or `[f"hello", f"world"]` (second `f` is not detected as keyword)@John Kitchin

Comment: I don't see that, {PATH} is the only keyword in that example, and it is highlighted correctly for me. The second example has no keywords in it, and both are just plain strings.

Comment: Please see, I tried to show it on the screenshot of what I am having: https://gist.github.com/avatar-lavventura/5af25ccc3de7e07b537fce2f14c6aac2#gistcomment-3168317

Comment: When I have a example like this (starting, ending, or middle of the string having `\n`), `print(f"Downloading => {key} \n")` ; variable(key) deos not show up with a different color, do you have the similar output? @John Kitchin

Comment: yes I see that too. the \n seems to break it, but I don't know why. `"f\\(['\"]\\{1,3\\}\\)\\(.+?\\)\\1"` also seems to work, but I have not checked it against all your other test cases.

Comment: Thank you, I was just curious about it maybe `\n` is a defines as specific symbol on python-mode or emacs

Comment: \n is just a newline character. I don't know why it doesn't get matched though by `[^\\1]` which should match any character that is not the opening quote.

Comment: Should we ask it as a question, which seems like an interesting case?

Comment: I asked it at https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/55586/regexp-for-matching-quoted-strings-that-may-have-control-characters-in-them

Comment: Thanks and appreciated your help @John Kitchin

Comment: There are some interesting approaches and explanations in the answers to the new question. I have updated this answer so it works with \n in it, but there may be a more robust answer that leverages syntax described at https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/55586/regexp-for-matching-quoted-strings-that-may-have-control-characters-in-them. It will take some work to make that also do what is done here though.

Comment: If you prefer not to highlight the `{`: change `"{[^}]*?}"` to `"{\\([^}]*?\\)}"` and change `(0 font-lock-variable-name-face t)` to `(1 font-lock-variable-name-face t)`

Comment: In `GNU Emacs 27.1` seems like it does not work :-(

Comment: Yeah this breaks almost all python font locking in emacs 27.1 :(

Comment: The fix seems to be to replace `python-font-lock-keywords` with `python-font-lock-keywords-maximum-decoration`.

Comment: Would it be working in `GNU Emacs 27.1` ? If yes, that would be awesome. Only replacing `python-font-lock-keywords` with `python-font-lock-keywords-maximum-decoration` would be enough? seems like it didn't have any affect  @John Kitchin

Comment: @JohnKitchin Sorry for pretty late comment. In some cases I have to use `{{` or `}}`  to add curly brakets into the string (https://stackoverflow.com/a/68254078/2402577). But the coloring get confused. Would it be possible to handle those cases as well? Example color: https://gist.github.com/avatar-lavventura/27bcfb5df8b9d243fa8bf4b7928d2254#gistcomment-3817024