# Emacs >27.1: How to highlight in different colors for variables inside `fstring` in python-mode

Tags: python, faces, font-lock, syntax-highlighting

I am using `python-mode` which colors the parameters.

When I concatinate strings the variable color is represented as different:
[image]

On the other hand, if I use `fstring`, the variable is not represented as different color:

[image: str]

Please note that, if I enter non-existing variable, `python-mode` detects it:

[image]

**[Q]** Is there any way to give a color to variables inside a `fstring` in `python-mode` for Emacs version `>27.1`?

---

Related answer for Emacs `<27.1`: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/55186/18414
When I apply it, it messes up all the original coloring in `Python-mode`. Everything becomes white except strings.

- [Regexp for matching quoted strings that may have control characters in them](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/55586/regexp-for-matching-quoted-strings-that-may-have-control-characters-in-them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using this:

```el
(if (version< "27.0" emacs-version)
    (setq python-font-lock-keywords-maximum-decoration
        (append python-font-lock-keywords-maximum-decoration
            '(("f\\(['\"]\\{1,3\\}\\)\\(.+?\\)\\1"
               ("{[^}]*?}"
            (progn (goto-char (match-beginning 0)) (match-end 0))
            (goto-char (match-end 0))
            (0 font-lock-variable-name-face t)))))))
```

Comment: In some cases I have to use `{{` or `}}` to add curly brakets into the string (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68253951/how-do-i-add-curly-brackets-to-f-strings-in-python-3/68254078#68254078). But the coloring get confused. Would it be possible to handle those cases as well? Example coloring in those cases: https://gist.github.com/avatar-lavventura/27bcfb5df8b9d243fa8bf4b7928d2254#gistcomment-3817024

Comment: Also can we add a condition to apply your function only for emacs `>27.1`? because it does not work for `<27.1` :-( // Even it works with `<27.1` that will be golden

Comment: You can add a test for emacs version (I edited my answer). For the "{{" case, I don't have solution yet.

Comment: Yay! Finally I am able to upgrade to emacs `>.27.1`

Comment: Sorry for pretty late comment, when I try `f"{variable}"` it shows `variable` as white white, it is same on your end or does it apply different color?

Comment: LightGoldenrod (yellow) for me (Face: font-lock-variable-name-face)

Comment: Could this be applied only for the string color in between `{}` and does not apply for the other variable colors?

Comment: you can use any face (even a specially created one) by replacing `font-lock-variable-name-face` with the face you want in the proposed code.

Comment: I was not able to figure out related face name only for the `{<variable_name>}`, I can try to ask it in different quation

Comment: Yes, I think you should ask another question.